# Selenium WebDriver / Java - Simulate Human Like Cursor Movement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to automate a simple task inside Facebook Ads Manager. This task involves setting up a campaign and uploading some ads. It can take a human 30 minutes to do this. However, they're doing the same thing every single time. Often with mistakes. **It's something that should be automated. Done without human emotion or mistakes.**

Facebook is very sensitive and I don't want it to ban me for the wrong reasons. So I need to feel human. I can take my time between clicks. However, the cursor movement itself needs to feel human. **I only need to simulate a real human click for ethical purposes.**

Say I get an element I want to move my cursor towards:

```
WebDriver driver;    

// Set file path of chrome driver
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");

// Create object
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

// Go to URL
driver.get("FACEBOOK URL");

// Get element
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Setup Campaign')]");
```

What is the best way to move my cursor towards this element as a real human would?

- A real human would first move the mouse. Not just click the element
- They would move the mouse/cursor slowly. It could take up to say 500-1000 milliseconds. Certainly not instantly.
- They would move the mouse/cursor in a curved fashion. Not just in a 100% straight line. Possibly, in a random fashion?  So some elements of randomness may be needed?

I'm quite new to Selenium, so any input would be greatly appreciated.

I am writing my code in Java :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebDriver doesn't use an operating system input; it communicates directly with the browser via http protocol. If you want to simulate communication like a 'real' mouse input you have to use an automation solution that uses operating system based frameworks. In case of Windows you can use e.g.:

1. https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI (read https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI/wiki/FAQ to get the knowledge how to configure Chrome to expose web controls for FlaUI)
2. https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver

Comment: The WinAppDriver looks very interesting. Especially, with Selenium-like language. Have we got any actionable code anywhere on moving the mouse? (Then making it feel human)?

Comment: Here is a java example (not for web app - as I said, you have to prepare browser to be able to interact with web app using these desktop targeted solutions):
https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/Samples/Java/CalculatorTest/src/test/java/CalculatorTest.java

Comment: I will be using Selenium with a software called MultiLogin.com This allows me to have many different browser instances. Each with 100% unique fingerprints in every way. I am not sure how they will integrate with this. They do support Selenium. What about the idea of executing Javascript with selenium? a small scrict each time to move the cursor from point to point?

Comment: I think that this page should be interesting to you
https://css-tricks.com/simulating-mouse-movement/

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is not exactly what you asked, but in this case I recommend you to use the Facebook API instead of selenium.

It's more stable than your approach and without the risk of getting banned.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/v12.0
```