# AutoIt Automation - How To Simulate Human Like Cursor Movement

Tags: selenium, autoit

I wrote a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64456577/selenium-webdriver-java-simulate-human-like-cursor-movement) on how to simulate human-like cursor movement with Selenium Web Driver and Java.

On this quest, **I discovered that Selenium Web Driver might not be the best fit.** It can't move the cursor directly. Or be able to in the fashion I need.

I don't need to physically move the mouse. Just as long as the website thinks the cursor is moving normally.

**I have learned about AutoIt automation and have built some scripts. I built a script to automate the Key Strokes I require when uploading a photo.** I had the idea to write the file path I need to upload to a .txt file. This is done in my Java App. Then when I call my AutoIt .exe file from Java. It then reads the .txt file. Gets the file path URL. It then does the operations necessary to paste the file path. Then click the "Open" button to upload the file to the website.

**Following on from this, I could save coordinates on where I want the mouse to go.** In a .txt file. Then when I fire the .exe AutoIt file. It reads this .txt file and does the "human-like" mouse behavior.

**I just need to know how to simulate real mouse/cursor movement in AutoIt?** A function I can give some coordinates to.

[I saw an article on doing in this CSS and JS... This should give you a good idea.](https://css-tricks.com/simulating-mouse-movement/)

Can anybody help? or offer any advice? Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at autoit documentation? Does [MouseClick](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm) do what you want? Any speed parameter >0 will not move the mouse instantly

Comment: I have read into this yes. However, it's far from human-like. A human doesn't move a mouse in a 100% straight line.

Comment: I need some level of noise or randomness. As outlined in how to fake do this in CSS + JS (With a pic of a cursor): https://css-tricks.com/simulating-mouse-movement/

Comment: Just from googling i found [this](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/105952-realistic-mousemove/?tab=comments#comment-748454) which seems to work pretty well for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a comment made on my question. That linked to a script. It works amazingly!

It produces nonlinear mouse movements better than I ever imagined :)

```
; Smoother Mouse Move
; by the DtTvB

; Ease in function
func __calci1($i, $sm)
    return $i ^ $sm;
endFunc

; Ease out function
func __calci2($i, $sm)
    return 1 - ((1 - $i) ^ $sm);
endFunc

; Ease in out function
func __calci($i, $sm)
    if ($i < 0.5) then
        return __calci1($i * 2, $sm) / 2;
    else
        return (__calci2(($i - 0.5) * 2, $sm) / 2) + 0.5;
    endIf
endFunc

; Ease backward function
func __calof($i, $sm)
    if ($i < 0.5) then
        return __calci($i * 2, $sm);
    else
        return __calci((1 - $i) * 2, $sm);
    endIf
endfunc

; MAIN FUNCTION
func mouseMove2($x2, $y2)
    $x1 = mouseGetPos(0);
    $y1 = mouseGetPos(1);
    $xv = random(-100, 100);
    $yv = random(-100, 100);
    $sm = random(1.5, 2.5);
    $m = random(50, 160);
    for $i = 0 to $m
        $ci = __calci($i / $m, $sm);
        $co = __calof($i / $m, $sm);
        $cx = $x1 + (($x2 - $x1) * $ci) + ($xv * $co);
        $cy = $y1 + (($y2 - $y1) * $ci) + ($yv * $co);
        mouseMove ($cx, $cy, 1);
    next
endFunc

; Test Script
mouseMove2 (512, 386);
```